# Use mod_rewrite, yet keeping the "?"

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm wasting hours here with .htaccess to make those nice looking URLs possible and reached a dead end. This is what worked for me in the past:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ app.php?_target=$1 [L]
```

Now I would like to extend this rule to support URLs like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/articles/regex-cheatsheet/?sortby=expression&order=asc&filter=numeric
```

[Here is a nice explanation](http://warpspire.com/posts/url-design/) for why I would like doing this. My rule looks like this now:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(.*)$ app.php?_target=$1&$2 [L]
```

I've [validated this expression](http://regexr.com?2t5j5), as I am no regEx expert and it seems OK. But, of course, it doesn't work :/

So does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the QSA (Query String Append) flag:

```
RewriteRule (.*) app.php?_target=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oh My God. It works! Thank you very much! I didn't know about the "QSA" flag - pretty handy, almost like those apache people expected this ;)